# How to communicate between HtmlService Javascript and Server Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script

I'd like to create my first Google Docs Script to generate an amount but it seems not working well like this :

```js
function onOpen(e) {
    DocumentApp.getUi().createAddonMenu()
        .addItem('Start', 'showSidebar')
        .addToUi();
}

function onInstall(e) {
    onOpen(e);
}

function showSidebar() {
    var ui = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('Sidebar').setTitle('Calcul tarification Icecom');
    DocumentApp.getUi().showSidebar(ui);
}

function calculPrice(compagnyType, hours) {
  // here I'm not able to get "compagnyType" and "hours"
  var pricePerDay = 300;
  switch (compagnyType) {
    case 'PME':
      pricePerDay = 350;
      break;
    case 'ESI':
      pricePerDay = 400;
      break;
    case 'GE' :
      pricePerDay = 450;
      break;
  }
  return pricePerDay * hours;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ssl.gstatic.com/docs/script/css/add-ons1.css">
<!-- The CSS package above applies Google styling to buttons and other elements. -->

<style></style>

<div class="sidebar branding-below">
  <form>
    <div class="block col-contain">
      <div class="col-one">
        <label for="compagnyType">Type de l'entreprise</label>
        <select id="compagnyType" name="compagnyType">
          <option>TPE</option>
          <option>PME</option>
          <option>ESI</option>
          <option>GE</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="block form-group">
      <label for="hours"><b>Nombre d'heures</b></label>
      <input type="text" id="hours" name="hours"/>
    </div>

   <div class="block" id="button-bar">
      <button class="blue" id="calculPrice">Calculer</button>
    </div>
  </form>
  <div id="result"></div>
</div>

<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script>
  $(function() {
    $('#calculPrice').click(calculPrice);
  });
  function calculPrice() {
    var compagnyType = $('select[name=compagnyType]').val();
    var hours = $('input[name=hours]').val();
    var result = google.script.run.calculPrice(compagnyType, hours);
    $('#result').text(result);
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A quick test demonstrates that you *are* receiving your parameters in `calculPrice()`:

```js
function calculPrice(compagnyType, hours) {
  Logger.log(JSON.stringify(arguments));
  ...
```

Log contains:

```
[15-05-29 09:09:21:770 EDT] {"0":"TPE","1":"23"}
```

Since the information is moving from the client side to the server side properly, let's look at the opposite direction. First, validate that your server function does `return` a value upon success... and it does. Here's the code that's expected to receive it on the client side:

```js
var result = google.script.run.calculPrice(compagnyType, hours);
$('#result').text(result);
```

It's expecting to set `result` with the return value of `google.script.run...`. Check the documentation for [`run`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/run), and you'll find that there is no return code. The way that the API works is through a **call-back** function. Unlike a function call that has a synchronous response, a call-back gets a response *asynchronously*, some time *after* the API call, by sending it as a parameter to another client-side function that you provide. In your html/javascript you should have:

```js
...
google.script.run
      .withSuccessHandler(showResult)   // response goes to this function
      .calculPrice(compagnyType, hours);
```

and add

```js
// Function to receive asynchronous response
function showResult( result ) {
  $('#result').text(result);   // << Here is where we display the result
}
```

```js
function onOpen(e) {
    DocumentApp.getUi().createAddonMenu()
        .addItem('Start', 'showSidebar')
        .addToUi();
}

function onInstall(e) {
    onOpen(e);
}

function showSidebar() {
    var ui = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('Sidebar').setTitle('Calcul tarification Icecom');
    DocumentApp.getUi().showSidebar(ui);
}

function calculPrice(compagnyType, hours) {
  // here I'm not able to get "compagnyType" and "hours"
  var pricePerDay = 300;
  switch (compagnyType) {
    case 'PME':
      pricePerDay = 350;
      break;
    case 'ESI':
      pricePerDay = 400;
      break;
    case 'GE' :
      pricePerDay = 450;
      break;
  }
  return pricePerDay * hours;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ssl.gstatic.com/docs/script/css/add-ons1.css">
<!-- The CSS package above applies Google styling to buttons and other elements. -->

<style></style>

<div class="sidebar branding-below">
  <form>
    <div class="block col-contain">
      <div class="col-one">
        <label for="compagnyType">Type de l'entreprise</label>
        <select id="compagnyType" name="compagnyType">
          <option>TPE</option>
          <option>PME</option>
          <option>ESI</option>
          <option>GE</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="block form-group">
      <label for="hours"><b>Nombre d'heures</b></label>
      <input type="text" id="hours" name="hours"/>
    </div>

   <div class="block" id="button-bar">
      <button class="blue" id="calculPrice">Calculer</button>
    </div>
  </form>
  <div id="result"></div>
</div>

<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script>
  $(function() {
    $('#calculPrice').click(calculPrice);
  });
  function calculPrice() {
    var compagnyType = $('select[name=compagnyType]').val();
    var hours = $('input[name=hours]').val();
    google.script.run
          .withSuccessHandler(showResult)   // response goes to this function
          .calculPrice(compagnyType, hours);
  }

  // Function to receive asynchronous response
  function showResult( result ) {
    $('#result').text(result);   // << Here is where we display the result
  }
</script>
```